# Battery Drain overnight with Ubuntu 22.04

Tags: nvidia, 22.04, power-management, laptop, battery

I'm using AMD Asus ROG Zephyrus G15, Ryzen 9 5900HS, Nvidia GeForce RTX 3080 Mobile, 32GB RAM.
I'm working on my computer on Ubuntu 22.04 alongside Windows 11.

After I finish my job, if I don't turn off the computer or return to Windows the Ubuntu drains 100(!) percents of my laptop's battery until the next morning even if Ubuntu on suspend and lid is closed, and even when I open the laptop at home after work he is hot like he ran serious process (I didn't have any process running).

Is there something I'm doing wrong? I saw a lot of people with battery problems using Ubuntu but they have different answer and I feel like every computer should have his best answer to this.

Thanks in advance for your help! :)

Comment: This is more likely a hardware problem: the system is controlled by BIOS not the OS during suspend. The bios waits for a "wake on" event and allows for usb charging devices. It is probably USB that is kept active during suspend (that drains a battery relatively quick). It should be a bios setting to switch this off.  In case this is not it edit the question stating that was not it and I'll remove this comment.

Comment: The laptop is in a case with no USB or any device connected to him:(